# Verilog FIR filter

Tags: filter, verilog, intel-fpga

Hello I am implementing an FIR filter in Verilog, using the DE2 board. For some reason the output out of the speakers is full of static, although it does appear to filter out some frequencies. Here is the code for the FIR:

```
// Local wires.
    wire read_ready, write_ready, read, write;
    wire [23:0] readdata_left, readdata_right;
    wire [23:0] writedata_left, writedata_right;

    assign writedata_left = output_sample;
    
    assign writedata_right = output_sample;
    assign read = 1;
    assign write = 1;
    
    wire [23:0] input_sample = readdata_left;
    
    reg [23:0] output_sample;
```

the input sample is put through the FIR, and the output sample is put to both left and right speakers for simplicity.

```
//The FIR filter
parameter N = 40;
reg signed[23:0] coeffs[39:0];
reg [23:0] holderBefore[39:0];

wire [23:0] toAdd[39:0];

// -- 1000-1100
always @(*)
begin
    coeffs[0]=24'b100000000110101001111110; // -- 1
    coeffs[1]=24'b100000000110100011011011; // -- 2
    coeffs[2]=24'b100000000111000100001100; // -- 3
    coeffs[3]=24'b100000000111111000101000;// -- 4
    coeffs[4]=24'b100000001000011111111100;// -- 5
    coeffs[5]=24'b100000001000011001011001;// -- 6
    coeffs[6]=24'b100000000111010001010011;// -- 7
    coeffs[7]=24'b100000000100100110111010;// -- 8
    coeffs[8]=24'b100000000000011010001101;// -- 9
    coeffs[9]=24'b000000000101101111000000;// -- 10
    coeffs[10]=24'b000000001101100001000100;// -- 11
    coeffs[11]=24'b000000010110111100000000;// -- 12
    coeffs[12]=24'b000000100001011111000001;// -- 13
     coeffs[13]=24'b000000101100101001010111;// -- 14
    coeffs[14]=24'b000000111000000000110100;// -- 15
    coeffs[15]=24'b000001000010101010011001;// -- 16
    coeffs[16]=24'b000001001100001011111000;// -- 17
    coeffs[17]=24'b000001010011111101111100;// -- 18
    coeffs[18]=24'b000001011001011001010010;// -- 19
    coeffs[19]=24'b000001011100010000110010;// -- 20
    coeffs[20]=24'b000001011100010000110010;// -- 20
    coeffs[21]=24'b000001011001011001010010;// -- 19
    coeffs[22]=24'b000001001100001011111000;// -- 18
    coeffs[23]=24'b000001001100001011111000;// -- 17
    coeffs[24]=24'b000001000010101010011001;// -- 16
    coeffs[25]=24'b000000111000000000110100;// -- 15
     coeffs[26]=24'b000000101100101001010111;// -- 14
    coeffs[27]=24'b000000100001011111000001;// -- 13
    coeffs[28]=24'b000000010110111100000000;// -- 12
    coeffs[29]=24'b000000001101100001000100;// -- 11
    coeffs[30]=24'b000000000101101111000000;// -- 10
    coeffs[31]=24'b100000000000011010001101;// -- 9
    coeffs[32]=24'b100000000100100110111010;// -- 8
    coeffs[33]=24'b100000000111010001010011;// -- 7
    coeffs[34]=24'b100000001000011001011001;// -- 6
    coeffs[35]=24'b100000001000011111111100;// -- 5
    coeffs[36]=24'b100000000111111000101000;// -- 4
    coeffs[37]=24'b100000000111000100001100;// -- 3
     coeffs[38]=24'b100000000110100011011011;// -- 2
    coeffs[39]=24'b100000000110101001111110;// -- 1
end

genvar i;

generate
for (i=0; i<N; i=i+1)
    begin: mult
        multiplier mult1(
          .dataa(coeffs[i]),
          .datab(holderBefore[i]),
          .out(toAdd[i]));
    end
endgenerate

always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or posedge reset)
begin
    if(reset)
        begin
            holderBefore[39]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[38]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[37]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[36]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[35]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[34]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[33]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[32]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[31]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[30]     <= 0;
                holderBefore[29]    <= 0;
                holderBefore[28]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[27]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[26]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[25]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[24]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[23]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[22]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[21]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[20]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[19]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[18]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[17]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[16]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[15]     <= 0;
                holderBefore[14]    <= 0;
                holderBefore[13]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[12]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[11]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[10]    <= 0;
            holderBefore[9]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[8]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[7]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[6]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[5]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[4]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[3]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[2]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[1]     <= 0;
            holderBefore[0]     <= 0;
            output_sample       <= 0;
        end
    else
        begin
            holderBefore[39]     <= holderBefore[38];
            holderBefore[38]     <= holderBefore[37];
            holderBefore[37]     <= holderBefore[36];
            holderBefore[36]    <= holderBefore[35];
            holderBefore[35]    <= holderBefore[34];
            holderBefore[34]    <= holderBefore[33];
            holderBefore[33]     <= holderBefore[32];
            holderBefore[32]     <= holderBefore[31];
            holderBefore[31]     <= holderBefore[30];
            holderBefore[30]     <= holderBefore[29];
            holderBefore[29]     <= holderBefore[28];
            holderBefore[28]     <= holderBefore[27];
            holderBefore[27]     <= holderBefore[26];
            holderBefore[26]     <= holderBefore[25];
            holderBefore[25]     <= holderBefore[24];
                holderBefore[24]    <= holderBefore[23];
            holderBefore[23]    <= holderBefore[22];
            holderBefore[22]    <= holderBefore[21];
            holderBefore[21]     <= holderBefore[20];
            holderBefore[20]     <= holderBefore[19];
            holderBefore[19]     <= holderBefore[18];
            holderBefore[18]     <= holderBefore[17];
            holderBefore[17]     <= holderBefore[16];
            holderBefore[16]     <= holderBefore[15];
            holderBefore[15]     <= holderBefore[14];
            holderBefore[14]     <= holderBefore[13];
            holderBefore[13]     <= holderBefore[12];
            holderBefore[12]    <= holderBefore[11];
            holderBefore[11]    <= holderBefore[10];
            holderBefore[10]    <= holderBefore[9];
            holderBefore[9]     <= holderBefore[8];
            holderBefore[8]     <= holderBefore[7];
            holderBefore[7]     <= holderBefore[6];
            holderBefore[6]     <= holderBefore[5];
            holderBefore[5]     <= holderBefore[4];
            holderBefore[4]     <= holderBefore[3];
            holderBefore[3]     <= holderBefore[2];
            holderBefore[2]     <= holderBefore[1];
            holderBefore[1]     <= holderBefore[0];
            holderBefore[0]     <= input_sample;
            output_sample <= (input_sample + toAdd[0] + toAdd[1] + 
                              toAdd[2] + toAdd[3] + toAdd[4] + toAdd[5] +
                              toAdd[6] + toAdd[7] + toAdd[8] + toAdd[9] + 
                              toAdd[10] + toAdd[11] + toAdd[12]+ toAdd[13] + toAdd[14] + 
                              toAdd[15] + toAdd[16] + toAdd[17] + toAdd[18] +
                              toAdd[19] + toAdd[20] + toAdd[21] + toAdd[22] + 
                              toAdd[23] + toAdd[24] + toAdd[25] +toAdd[26] + toAdd[27] + toAdd[28] + toAdd[29] +
                              toAdd[19] + toAdd[20] + toAdd[21] + toAdd[22] + 
                              toAdd[30] + toAdd[31] + toAdd[32]+ toAdd[33] + toAdd[34] + toAdd[35] + toAdd[36] +
                              toAdd[37] + toAdd[38] + toAdd[39]);
        end
end

//The multiplier
module multiplier (dataa,datab,out);
input [23:0]dataa;
input [23:0]datab;
reg [47:0]result;
output[23:0]out;
always@(*)begin
    result = dataa*datab;
end
assign out = result[46:24]; 
endmodule
```

Granted that the coefficients are correct, is there something wrong with the code? I assume there is a problem with the representation of the coefficients in binary, or the multiplier is wrong but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why represent the coefficients in binary? Why not just use hex or decimal values, they would be easier to read. You seem to be implying 40 Multipliers, and doing and addition of 40 values. I am surprised that it synthesis and meets timing. 40 Multipliers must take up a lot of area, and the time for a 40 input adder to settle must be quite long. Was there any warnings or errors with synthesis?

Comment: unless your first coefficient is 1 you probably do not want to have `input_sample` directly in output_sample equation.

Comment: The synthesis does take a lot of time, but does not produce any errors. how would I represent -0.1984 as decimal in Verilog? and yes they are meant to be signed, and I though that having 'reg signed' made the coefficients signed. How would I make multiplier signed? Thank you for your response.

Comment: for the coefficients multiply by 2^fractional bits. So you end up with an integer. Hex is normally used as it is more compact.

Answer (score 3):

The multiplier is not performing signed multiplication.

Verilog defaults to unsigned, if any part of an equation is unsigned it will be come unsigned. If a bit selection is made (even if it is the full width) the arithmetic will be come unsigned.

The following code should perform a signed arithmetic.

```
module multiplier (
  input      signed [23:0] dataa,
  input      signed [23:0] datab,
  output reg signed [23:0] out
);
reg signed [47:0] result;

  always @* begin
    result = dataa*datab;
    out    = result[46:24];
  end  
endmodule
```

Your not capturing the the MSB of `result` into `out` which would look like a gain error on unsigned or positive numbers, but might could loose the sign of negative numbers.

When you perform the sum into `output_sample` there is a possibility that the numbers overflow. for every addition you should add 1 bit of headroom, then limit. May be add some flags to record if it is overflowing/clipping at this stage.

Comment: I have a problem.  Why does the out intercept bits 24 to 46 of result?

Comment: @benjstark because that was part of the original question, I assume the data had to be normalised, ie sum of 2 elements is normalised by shifting right a bit (gain of 0.5). Otherwise it is just handling the expected bit growth that occurs in the arithmetic.  Look up how to perform fractional fixed point calculations.